# Regular expression to select single words inside parentheses using stringr

Tags: regex, stringr

I specified that I'm using `stringr` because its character escaping is not "standard" regex escaping.

I want to detect strings that have a single word inside parentheses. Thus, I want to detect

`"Men's shirt (blue)"`

and not detect

`"Blade Runner (Director's cut)"`

If it helps simplify the regex, all the parenthetical parts are always at the end of the string.

I have attempted

`str_detect(my_string, "\\(\\w?\\)")` which yields no results and

`str_detect(my_string, "\\(\\S\\)$")` which returns everything including multiple words

as well as various combinations using //S, with or without the $, etc.

When I look for other stack overflow answers, I usually find slightly different questions whose answers are simply "use this:" along with what seems like an incomprehensible regex using lookaheads and other seemilgly too-complicated things. I thank you for a little explanation on why the (probably obvious and simple) regex works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I didn't hit upon the //S+ in my combinations. I was checking for a single non-space character, not one or more non-space characters. This solution works:

`str_detect(desc, "\\(\\S+\\)$")`